# Selenium WebDriverWait - Cannot click button

Tags: java

Hope someone can help with this problem. The issue is

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (885, 86). Other element would receive the click: ...

The java code is showed below:

```
    //Thread.sleep(10000);   

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

    WebElement wSelectFI = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
            By.xpath("//*[@id=\"filterForm\"]/div[1]/span[2]/button[1]"))); 

    wSelectFI.click();
```

For the wSelectFI, if I use

```
String textValue = wSelectFI.getText();
```

Then the textValue is correct, so now I get the correct webElement. But when I use "click" method, the error occurs. If I use

```
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

in the code, the result is correct. And if I debug the code, the result is correct too. So I guess the error is the overlay of the element. I tried to add the code

```
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", wSelectFI);
    wSelectFI.click();
```

and the code

```
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,"+wSelectFI.getLocation().x+")");
    wSelectFI.click();
```

Both of them did not work. is anyone know how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

The following code solved my error

```
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", wSelectFI);
```